# Yii - about jquery ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, frameworks, yii

I am writing a shop application, and I have a question.

As you know ajax in Yii looks like

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
        '',
        array("cart/add/id/$item->id"),
        array(
            'update'=>'#cart',
        ),
        array('class' => "button_basket")
    );
?>
```

This code updates the div with `id = cart`. How can I update the other elements on the page? For example on the Cart page, I am removing via ajax one item and I need to update the Total price, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you'll need to write some javascript, preferably a function that will read the response from the server, and make changes in the ui accordingly.

If you go through the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail) for `ajaxLink();`, you'll see that the third parameter is [ajaxOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajax-detail) which takes the options of [jQuery's ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Therefore you can write a callback function for the [success event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events). And in this function you can make changes to your ui.

Sample code:

```
<?php
 echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    '',
    array("cart/add/id/$item->id"),
    array(
        // 'update'=>'#cart', this will be ignored when you have success callback
        'success'=>'js:successFunctionName',
    ),
    array('class' => "button_basket")
 );
?>
```

Somewhere in the current view you can use [`registerScript`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail) to output the function to the view:

```
Yii::app->clientScript->registerScript('scriptname','
    function successFunctionName(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // write awesome javascript to change ui
    }
');
```